# Windows App Certification Kit error after clicking "Click here to view full report"

Tags: windows-8, wack

I am getting an `Unhandled exception` error after running the Windows App Certification Kit and clicking on the "*Click here to view full report*" link. Is this a problem with my application or is the Windows App Certification Kit crashing?

The error is `Class Not Registered` and here are the details:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Class not registered
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Now thats just the dumbest thing ever..... Not the question but the reason why. I saw the native w32 exception and thought the worst.

Comment: @Terrance What's dumb about that? All errors returned by Win32 functions are converted to Win32Exceptions. "Class not registered" is a standard and sensible Win32 error message.

Comment: Okay so dumb might be a gross oversimplification. Generally speaking a win32 error for a vanilla win32 application, this could be a perfectly sensible error message, however in a case such as this where OP is just trying to use the Win 8 app certification, I felt that the error message unintuitive as it does not explain to the user what his problem actually is.

Comment: If the real problem is that the browser used is the incorrect browser for this particular app (doesn't matter if due to some active X, COM, or win32 api thing) then if possible maybe the error message should reflect that the browser is the issue.(Note* IDK if it makes more sense to mention this but, I was referring to the original version of the question prior to any edits. )

Answer (score 8):

You'll get this error if Chrome is registered as the default application associated with .htm files (I didn't see it with Firefox).

It's specifically occurring as it tries to launch the Validation.htm file with the results of WACK, so in that regard it's not your app causing the issue, and WACK is indeed complete.  Validation.htm is located in the bowels of your Visual Studio solution directory, under the Release (or Debug) folder, so you can open it straight from File Explorer in whatever your default browser is.

Comment: Just wanted to add - this happens on *any* link that WACK has on it if Chrome is your default - for example, the 'download update' link will do this as well.

Comment: @ChrisSkardon take a look at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156400

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying, and I don't want to change my default browser. Just go to:

\bin\Debug\ValidationResult.htm

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. I just uninstalled Chrome & Firefox from my system. And the there was no error.
Whereas I was able to view the full report of certification in the location given below:-

```
C:\Users\vishwajeet.kumar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKit\ValidationResult.htm
```

The file `ValidationResult.htm` contains the full report of the certification.

Comment: Thanks Auri. You shared the information that we can also view the full validation report in either of the following two locations:- \bin\Debug\ValidationResult.htm if the application is built in Debug mode. And \bin\Release\ValidationResult.htm if the application is built in Release mode.